How to implement automatic context propagation with OpenTelemetry in Confluent Kafka?
I am working on a distributed system that involves EMQX receiving data and sending it to a Confluent Kafka server. I want to implement automatic context propagation using OpenTelemetry across these services, but I'm unsure how to handle this since I'm using Confluent Kafka, not the Kafka SDK directly.
Here's what I would like to achieve:
When EMQX sends data to Kafka, I want to propagate the tracing context using OpenTelemetry.
On the Kafka consumer side, I want to extract the tracing context and continue the trace.
